# Virus Asking To Format External Hard Drive

Tags: windows-7, virus, anti-virus, malware, trojan

I have an external harddrive. Whenever I put its USB into the USB port of my laptop, it asks me to format my hard drive. I think this is because of some sort of virus. Can someone please help me to sort out this issue ?? I have very important documents inmy hard drive. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds more like file system corruption than a virus. Are you still able to mount the drive? If so run a chkdsk /f on it.

Comment: I am able to mount it on macbook but on on my Dell laptop.

Comment: -1 you make a wild assumption straight away in your question it's not like you've seen that viruses ask you or people to format hard drives, you just imagined it completely, that is not how to look at things that aren't working or how to look at things that are working, or how to look at anything.

Comment: If the drive works with your macbook I highly recommend you get your very important documents copied off of there.

Comment: The macbook is around 5 years old .. and has very less space .. is there any other way around by which I can rectify this issue on my Dell lappy itself ?

Comment: It is also possible that OP has a virus, I'm encountering the same situation. An infected Windows host tries to make the user format any FAT32 partition, but not NTFS partitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably is not malware.

Try repairing the file system disk using [`chkdsk`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc730714%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) utility.

Example:

```
chkdsk d: /f
```

**Note**: `d` is your drive letter.

If the above does not work use a tool to recover important data or try using a Linux distribution to see the files.

Comment: format? if the other answers are true (which probably are) and he has a valid volume that Windows can't read, you're asking him to lose data?

Comment: @RichHomolka Ok.. edited.

Comment: should I use the command `chkdsk d: /f` or `chkdsk d: /r` ? Can you also tell me the difference ?

Comment: @kamalbhai the two parameters can be used together.

Answer (score 4):

It is not virus that prompts you to format the external hard drive. It's because either Windows is unable to detect the file system on the external hard drive or because your external hard drive is corrupted.

You can use a program such as HFSExplorer to read Mac's file system on Windows. Just Google the software name.

Comment: actually I had this problem in my other hard drive b4 too.. but then I found some `.exe` files in Macbook. I deleted these and then the external HD started working fine as usual on windows too. But this time, I am unable to delete those `.exe` files cuz they are broken as told by macbook. So, I think it is definitely because of a virus.

Comment: and the software you recommended can't load the drive. I am telling you, it is because of a virus.

Comment: If the .exe files are reappearing even after deleting them then either your system or system + external hard disk are infected with viruses. I'd recommend you to perform a through scan of both the things.

Comment: I tried to scan it in windows using norton, it was unable to scan it. and secondly, do you know how to scan on Macbook ? I tried to verify and repair it, but that also went in vain. It was futile.

Comment: If you know to use Linux then I'd suggest to install ClamWin and scan the entire hard-drive to remove any virus. Or ask for help from one of your tech-savvy friend or call your computer technician. If data is really important to you then I'd recommend you to contact data recovery store.

Comment: Do you know how to mount the external hard drive in Ubuntu working on VMWare station ?

Comment: It should automatically detect the external drive.

Comment: It aint doing so .. damn .. m so stucked rite now..

Comment: You should probably get some help from a tech-savvy friend or a computer technician.

Answer (score 3):

Its probably formatted with Mac file system which windows cannot read. And when Windows cannot read a file system, it asks you to format the drive.

If this indeed is the case, you just have to convert drive back to FAT32 or NTFS and I don't quite know how to do that without affecting data.

Comment: I dont think that it is formatted. Windows can detect the hard drive but on asking it to open the Drive.. it prompts me to Format the drive.

Comment: That's exactly what I am talking about. By formatted, I meant drive uses Mac file system. Easiest way to check is plug it back into Macbook and check file system

Comment: @kamalbhai: Move the data off on your Macbook, plug the thing into your Dell, say yes to format, put test data on there and check if you can read and write to it on the Macbook.

Comment: the Macbook doesnot have space for 1.5TB of data .. :(

Comment: in that case, see ASRM's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with a virus. Simply put, Mac OSX and Windows use different file systems. It is likely that you set the disk up on an OSX system and only now are you attempting to read it from a Windows machine.

Natively, Windows cannot read OSX file systems (typically HFS) or vice-versa (Windows normally uses NTFS). Commonly, they can both read FAT filesystems but this format is unattractive due to limited file sizes. You can, however, use a software called MacDrive to read OSX filesystems on Windows machines. Be warned though, it is not free.

http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive